# Order SELECT statement by sum of another table?

Tags: mysql

I know questions like this have been asked before, but I'm not sure how I can apply it to my code. I have two tables. I have an `entry` table that stores entries like this:

```
id | name | description
1    Test   Test entry
```

In the other table, I have a `rating` table like this:

```
id | entryid | rating
1  | 1       | 1
2  | 1       | -1
```

I want to list all the entries in the first table, but order them by the total rating. So, in this example, Entry #1 would have a rating of 0, because 1 + -1 = 0. Is there a way that I can do this with a query?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You mention `COUNT`, but your description is `SUM`ming the data, and you mention `ORDER BY`, but ordering by is sorting, and there's no information in your text about sorting anything. Can you edit and clarify, also to provide table names? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I didn't realize it was a sum until I was writing the thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2aa3/4). You just need to use `Sum` to count all ratings per each `entryID`.

Query:

```
select r.entryid, sum(r.rating)
from ratings r
group by r.entryid
;
```

Result:

```
ENTRYID     SUM(R.RATING)
1           -1
2           2
```

Final Query:

```
select e.id, e.name, sum(r.rating)
from entry e
left join 
ratings r
on r.entryid = e.id
group by e.id
;
```

Final Results:

```
ID  NAME    SUM(R.RATING)
1   Test1   -1
2   Test2   2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inline view like this:

```
select id, `name`, description from (
select t1.id, t1.`name`, t1.description, sum(t2.rating) as sum_rating
from
t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.entryid
group by t1.id, t1.`name`, t1.description
) as t 
order by sum_rating desc
```

So, you calculate the sums of all the related ratings, and then order by those sums from the inner part of the query. If some rows of your first table don't have any ratings, then replace the inner join with a left join.

Comment: What's an "inline view"? That looks like a subquery.

Comment: But I don't think you need the subquery, you can just use `ORDER BY` on the join itself.

Comment: @Barmar - I don't think CommunistPancake wanted to select the sum, just to order by it, so the inline view/subquery is needed to "hide" the sum from the output columns, but make it available for ordering. Strangely, the accepted answer does not have an order by clause!!

Comment: Ahh, most people don't bother hiding extraneous columns like this, they just ignore them in the application code. It's also possible to write `order by sum(t2.rating)` without including it in the `select` clause.